# SUBSTR and add "-" to a number

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select SUBSTR (DriveID, 1, 8) from Admin

Original term : D255FA8E
```

how can I add `"-"` at the beginning and at the end so the term will be like this : `D-255FA-8E`

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONCAT` on `SUBSTR`, like this:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTR(DriveID,1,1)
    ,   '-'
    ,   SUBSTR(DriveID,2,5)
    ,   '-'
    ,   SUBSTR(DriveID,6,2)
    )
FROM test
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c98a/4).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try,

```
CONCAT(LEFT(DriveID, 1), '-', SUBSTR(DriveID, 2, LENGTH(DriveID)-3), '-', RIGHT(DriveID, 2))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this & it is also the simplest way .

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('D255FA8E', 'D', 'D-'),'D-255FA','D-255FA-')
```